# How to sample from a reconstructed pdf

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, sampling

Suppose, that we have a process that generates events. Subsequently these events are recorded and stored in a histogram. Say we have a source that emits particles and subsequently a histogram is build based on each individual particle's energy. Suppose further, that the bins of the histogram have varying widths, some being wider and some narrower. Following this process one can construct a spectral density $\phi(e_i)$ by counting how many times a certain energy falls within a particular histogram energy interval corresponding to a bin 
$e_{i-1},e_i$ with a width 
$$
\Delta_i=e_{i}-e_{i-1}.
$$
This histogram represents a discrete pdf. A discrete pdf with bins of uniform width can be sampled by inverting the cumulative cdf given by
$$
F_E(e)=\sum_{e_i\le e} \phi(e_i),
$$
with the associated inverse cdf
$$
F^{-1}(x)=\inf\{e:F(e)\ge x\}
$$
The question is how to sample if the histogram's bins have varying widths. Namely, since the widths $\Delta_i$ of the bins are non uniform, should one sample from
$$
\phi(e_i) \text{ or from } \frac{\phi(e_i)}{\Delta_i}.
$$
With the associated pdfs 
$$
F_E(e)=\sum_{e_i\le e} \phi(e_i) \text{ or } F_E(e)=\sum_{e_i\le e} \frac{\phi(e_i)}{\Delta_i}.
$$
I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the distribution function $F(x)$ directly.  Generate a random number $R$ and find the interval where $F(e_{i-1})\lt R\le F(e_i)$.

Comment: That is correct, the question is how to compute the cdf. Which one of the two methods as given in  the question.

Comment: Use $F(e)=\sum_{e_i\le e}\phi(e_i)$.  Equal spacing is irrelevant.

Comment: I don't understand this, could you please elaborate.

Comment: I am a little confused about your definition of $\phi$.  What I have in mind is first get the total number of events.  Next divide the number in each interval by the total, call that $f((e_i)$ for the interval.  Then $F(e)=\sum_{e_i\le e}f(e_i)$.

Comment: Consider the histogram to be an energy spectrum. The tricky part is that the bins of the histogram are with different widths. Since pdf is probability per unit mass, I guess that i would have to divide by the width of the bins.

Comment: To get the pdf, you first normalize the histogram by dividing the number of events is each bin by the total number of events.  This results in the total probability $f(e_i)$ for the interval.  To get the pdf you want you divide each $f(e_i)$ by the length of the interval.  To clarify our confusion, you need to describe exactly the mathematics to define $\phi(e_i)$.  Is it the fraction of events in the interval or something else?

Comment: $\phi(e_i)$ is the fraction of events. If all slots/bins are equal width then it does not matter. The question only arises when the bins are non-equal length. A narrow bin would get less events than a wide one. How to take that fact into account when sampling the empirical pdf?

Comment: I think I finally understand your problem.  The pdf is as you described $\frac{\phi(e_i)}{\Delta_i}$.  However when integrating the pdf to get the cdf you must take into account the length of the interval, so the summation terms are $\frac{\phi(e_i)}{\Delta_i}\times \Delta_i=\phi(e_i)$.

Comment: If you remember from elementary calculus, the integral of a constant (c) over an interval [a,b] is c(b-a).

Comment: The integral is not important here. The question is, whether I should divide by the bin width. I am accumulating a histogram with different width bins, from which I would like to draw samples. The answer to the question is NO and I checked it numerically. Therefore we are on a different tune.

Comment: In order to draw a sample you need to first get the bin from which to sample.  To do that you need to use the pdf , using the random number as I described.  Once you get a bin, sample from the bin by assuming uniform within the bin.

Comment: Well this i know already and is is also what i wrote in my question. The problem was whether or whether not i have to divide by the bin widths to "normalize the pdf". The answer is no. The cdf is obtained just by summing the "raw" histogram values. Checked that one numerically

Comment: Clarification:  The pdf is defined by dividing the histogram by the bin width.  To get the cdf you multiply the pdf by the bin width (getting the histogram back).  Your approach is correct.  In essence the histogram for each bin is the integral of the pdf over that bin.

Comment: I hope so :). At least the numerical example proved the point. My confusion comes from the fact that in physics energy plots are normalized to the bin width. If i would do that to the histogram, however, the results are wrong.

Comment: It looks like we're OK.  It seems that the problem was in the definition of histogram.  The division by the bin width seems to lead to confusion.